# I want to sync and sort a list of data periodically on Firebase. How do I do this?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I'm developing an app that takes in raw data from Google Sheets and sorts it in an appropriate manner.

Functionality that I'm looking for:
If a row gets added in the google sheets, the appropriate data needs to be added to my Firebase database. Next, I need to check if the field 'email' in this new data already exists. If it does, I need to ignore it and if it doesn't, create a new field. If I use ValueEventListener for this purpose, each time the data is added, it returns the whole list. How do I use ChildEventListener in this case?

My data structure:

[image]

You can assume that the 'email' will always be at '3', 'mobile code' at '4' and so on.

I am not sure how to retrieve the data with ChildEventListener as the path keeps changing for each person. However, the data is successfully being added from the google sheets to the Firebase so you can ignore that part.

Comment: Have you seen this [gist](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/44ad12f4836e79ca9fa11ba5af6955f7)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! But my question is about how to sort the data after that!